# Storing backup keys (2FA) for online accounts

Tags: passwords, password-management, multi-factor, backup

So I spent the day looking for a good solution of storing the backup keys or the 2FA codes and can't seem to find a convenient way for me, many people have different takes on this, so far I found 2 ways that could work for me and I would like to know which solution is best between this, from a security/convenience standpoint:

1. Making a second BitWarden account just for the 2FA codes, I have 2 questions with this:

- Should I activate 2FA with the second BitWarden account too?
- Should I use another password manager like KeePass?

2. Buying 1 or 2 flash drives and storing the keys there of course encrypting them using VeraCrypt/Keepass.

Or maybe the 2 combined?

Also if anyone good another good solution please feel free to let me know

Thanks!

Comment: Just print out the QR codes on paper then they are protected against all online attacks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you shouldn't create another Bitwarden account only for your backup codes.
It's highly inconvenient. And you will have the same problems you have now.

Instead I think you should store them somewhere else. **Encrypted** and **not online**.
Your solution which is to store the keys on an encrypted flash drive (or even two) is indeed a good solution.

Of course you can combine the two. It would add a layer of security. If you decide to do this, then **yes** enable 2FA on your second account ! Then store these codes on an encrypted USB flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

KeePass is a good solution. There are implementations for all OS, can be stored on a USB key, and synced via Dropbox, and uses [strong encryption](https://keepass.info/help/base/security.html#:%7E:text=KeePass%20database%20files%20are%20encrypted,%2C%20URLs%2C%20notes%2C%20etc.) like AES.

I use it on my desktop, then use Dropbox to sync it to my phone.